# Entity Framework AlterColumn does not change database when query is run

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use migrations to change the datatype of a column from int to string and replacing the integer values of an enum to the string representation.

My code:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Tid", "Status", c => c.String(nullable:false));

foreach (var status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TimelisteStatus)).Cast<TimelisteStatus>())
{
    Sql(String.Format("UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = '{0}' WHERE [Status] = {1}", status, status.ToString("D")));
}
```

and output from migrations:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"0" -verbose
Target database is: 'AdTid' (DataSource: ., Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Reverting migrations: [201401091224116_Migration
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tid] ALTER COLUMN [Status] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = 'Kladd' WHERE [Status] = 10
UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = 'Avvist' WHERE [Status] = 20
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Kladd' to data type int.
```

If i copy paste the commands into SQL Manager, everything works fine, so my question: Is there a way to force the ALTER TABLE command to commit before i run my update statement?

Comment: ddl statements such as `alter table` do not require to be committed. does the user with which you connect your application to sql server have appropriate rights?

Comment: Just figured it out, UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = 'Kladd' WHERE [Status] = 10 needs to be UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = 'Kladd' WHERE [Status] = '10' 

For some reason it works in management studio, but not when using migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, but here goes:

```
foreach (var status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TimelisteStatus)).Cast<TimelisteStatus>())
{
    Sql(String.Format("UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = '{0}' WHERE [Status] = {1}", status, status.ToString("D")));
}
```

has to be altered to:

```
foreach (var status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TimelisteStatus)).Cast<TimelisteStatus>())
{
    Sql(String.Format("UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = '{0}' WHERE [Status] = '{1}'", status, status.ToString("D")));
}
```

That again creates the SQL:

```
UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = 'Kladd' WHERE [Status] = '10'
```

instead of

```
UPDATE dbo.Tid SET [Status] = 'Kladd' WHERE [Status] = 10
```

Why the second statement works in management studio, but not in migrations I really can't answer. The problem occurs because I alter the column to a varchar column before I run the Update statement and 10 is no longer an integer, but a string '10'.